# AngularJs: Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- DonorerCtrl

Tags: html, angularjs, api, resources, angular-resource

I am trying to load in a list of "donors" for my angular application. I get the data from an API, but I doesn't work the way I want it to. I get this error:

$resourceProvider <- $resource <- DonorerCtrl

In my DonorerCtrl class I have the following code:

```
angular.module("testApp").controller("DonorerCtrl",
function($scope, $http, $resource) {
    console.log("Test fra donorerCtrl");

    $scope.donorerResource = $resource("http://bloodadmin.cloudapp.net/api/users/:donorid"),
    {id: "@donorid"}, { update: {method: "PUT"}};

    $scope.donorerVisits = $scope.donorerResource.query();

    $http (
        {
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://bloodadmin.cloudapp.net/api/donors"
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.donorerVisits = data;
        }).error(function() {
            alert("error");
        });

    $scope.donorerVisits = [];

});
```

I try to load it in my HTML file with this code:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fornavn</th>
            <th>Efternavn</th>
            <th>Køn</th>
            <th>Fødselsdag</th>
            <th>Læs mere</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="visit in donorerVisits">
            <td>{{visit.firstname}}</td>
            <td>{{visit.lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{visit.sex}}</td>
            <td>{{visit.age}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-default">Læs mere</button></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In my Index html I load in these JS files:

```
<!-- JS -->
<script src="libs/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="libs/angular-resource.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Angular Custom -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module("testApp", ['ui.router']);
</script>

<script src="js/controllers/HjemCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/DonorerCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/BlodCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/navigation.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
angular.module("testApp", ['ui.router', 'ngResource']);
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work, but now I have this error: 
index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://bloodadmin.cloudapp.net/api/donors. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You need to enable [CORS](https://gist.github.com/mlynch/be92735ce4c547bd45f6) on server side.